# UICollectionViewCell show wrong image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have UICollectionView with an UIImageView inside the UICollectionViewCells. 
I use this to popolate:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    int index = (int)indexPath.row;
    NSString* image = [imagesUri objectAtIndex:index];

    if( [recipeImageView image] == nil){
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:image];
        recipeImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        recipeImageView.image = img;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

All works fine, but when I scroll, the image inside the cells is wrong. Debugging i see that the img variable is always correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not setting image properly to the imageview, it will assign the image only if the imageview doesn't contain image else if someother image is already assigned it will bring that up.

Comment: what will be the else case? if you have certain requirement write it, and it will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you subclass your `UICollectionViewCell` (you really should, and move some of this code out of your view controller), you can override the `perpareForReuse`and set the `imageView.image = nil` before the cell is used again.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're reusing the cell, once recipeImageView has been set, you don't overwrite it - you only set the image if recipeImageView.image == nil, and that's only on the first load.

You need to set the image with the new value every time you load the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason the wrong image is displayed is because the `if( [recipeImageView image] == nil)` condition returns false when a previous cell is reused. When a previous cell (cell at row 1 for example) is reused (at row 10), it will contain and imageView with an image (from row 1) that is not nil. Therefore the if condition above returns false and the image (at row 10) won't be updated with the new image.

Suggested solution: remove the if condition and always update the imageView with a new image.

Comment: I've added it because with a lot of image the scroll becomes little fluid.. how can I keep scroll fluid?

Comment: You can load images into memory on viewDidLoad and keep the UIImage objects in an array. What is slowing the scroll is the fact that you are loading images from files each time. Remember to clear the images if didReceiveMemoryWarning is called on your UIViewController

Comment: @Pol, you can either use images that fit exactly the frame container as small images will load faster(thumb images) or you can use async queue to read your images into ram before presenting

Comment: Yup of course, but it's a good start. Also have a read about the concept of lazy loading and think about how you can apply it to your specific problem.